# dba_scheduler_job_run_details and dbms_output

Tags: oracle, logging, jobs, dbms-scheduler, dbms-output

**dba_scheduler_job_run_details** is capable to keep an dbms_output.put_line lines in **dba_scheduler_job_run_details.output** column. And it is so, when the job flows and exits normally. However, when I explicitly call dbms_scheduler.stop_job - all the output is missed.
How to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can avoid this, in the same way that if you killed off a SQL*PLus session that was running a procedure, you would not see the output either, because DBMS_OUTPUT simply puts data into an array and the calling environment is then responsible for retrieving that information and putting it somewhere (eg outputting to the terminal).  You kill/stop the calling environment..and there's nothing left to go and get that output.

A better option would be to not utilise DBMS_OUTPUT solely as a debugging/instrumentation mechanism. Much better options exist in terms of capturing debugging information including viewing it from alternate sessions in real time etc.

Check out Logger at https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger. It is in common use by many in the Oracle community.